# Is it possible to pick and choose which y-label values inside a linechart of mpandroidchart are displayed?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Below is the chart I am trying to create using MPAndroidChart library:

[required_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdIjX.png)

To create this graph, I need some way to tell the linechart to only show two y-values "Average" and "You". I also need a way to draw a vertical grid-line that only goes up to the circle/y-value. I have searched for tutorials, SO articles, issues on MPAndroidChart github as well as the wiki, but I'm still uncertain how to create the graph above. Is there a way to create this graph with MPAndroidChart? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating multiple data sets and style them differently. The 1st one should contain all the values, including "Average" and "You", enable fill color and disable drawing the circles.

Then, create a new set with a single value (average) and give it a different style. Do the same with the "you" value.

Good luck !